# Google colab printing class object different then print() function

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I always think that google colab just print (by default the end edgy var) the var in the last line but came with this unexpect output that is different from print() function. Anyone can explain why this happens?

Dont know why came two differents output

[image]

Comment: you could crop image.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty printing is enabled by default. The pretty print for classes and types seems to be determined by [_type_pprint()](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/e4ce5023ac90dee412387c0e9c6a2bbdce0b0b3c/IPython/lib/pretty.py#L745) and you can see that it can be the module and name:

> ```python
> p.text(mod + '.' + name)
> ```

You can toggle pretty printing on/off using [the `%pprint` line magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=pretty#magic-pprint). Example with the outputs as comments:

```python
class Foo:
  pass

print(Foo)

# <class '__main__.Foo'>

Foo

# __main__.Foo

%pprint

# Pretty printing has been turned OFF

Foo

# <class '__main__.Foo'>
```

With the pretty printing off the output seems to be the same as the `__repr__`.

[Demo in Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HYS5q4fuRchF8qgi7nONIwOiCIPABe6C)